# Given $T(A) = A^t$ in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$. Find the polynomials and find if it's diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Given the vector space $M_{n\times n} (\mathbb R)$ and a transformation $T(A) = A^t$ (transpose):
>
> 1. Find $m_T$, $P_T$ (the minimum polynomial and the characteristic polynomial respectively.)
> 2. Find if $T$ is diagonalizable, if so, find a diagonalization basis and the representation matrix in that basis.

But how can I exactly find what $T$ does on $A^t$ if the basis has $n$ vectors?
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: $T$ is an endomorphism of the space $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ which has dimension $n^2$. a basis of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is formed by matrixes with exactly one coefficient equal to 1 and all others zero. try to compute the matrix of $T$ in this basis (it will be a matrix of size $n^2 \times n^2$)

Comment: $T^2$ is the identity while $\pm T$ is not, so the minimal polynomial is $x^2-1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $T\circ T=\mathrm{Id}$ hence the polynomial $x^2-1$ which has simple roots $-1$ and $1$ annihilates $T$ hence $T$ is diagonalizable and since $T\neq \pm \mathrm{Id}$ then $x^2-1$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$, moreover since 
$$M_n(\mathbb{R})=S_n(\mathbb{R})\oplus A_n(\mathbb{R})$$
then the matrix of $T$ in a basis correspondant to this decomposition is $\mathrm{diag}(1,\ldots,1,-1,\ldots,-1)$ with $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\dim S_n(\mathbb{R})$ eigenvalues $1$ and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\dim A_n(\mathbb{R})$ eigenvalues $-1$ hence the characteristic polynomial is 
$$\chi_T(x)=(x-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}(x+1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$

Comment: I understood till the point of the minimum polynomial, but not hte rest. What is $S_n$ and $A_n$?

Comment: $S_n$ is the subspace of symmetric matrices and $A_n$ is the subspace of antisymmetric matrices.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome.